# How can I link 'legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj'?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/link-options?view=msvc-140

I added 'legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj' to the linker command line additional options as shown, but LNK1181 came out and I could not build.
I am using Visual Studio 2015.

I searched for legacy_stdio_float_rounding.obj but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

> This behavior update is available in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.2 and later

You're not using VS2019 but VS2015. That's already the legacy version, you can't get the *new* behavior.